# mailto link doesn't work in gmail

Tags: mailto

I'v encountered an issue with gmail **mailto:** link, the link works fine for Outlook in both iOS and BB OS.

See below:

**mailto:firstname.lastname@gmail.com?subject=thread#:1234123123123**

But in gmail, the subject **thread#:1234123123123** got truncated because **#** symbol.

```
Subject: thread
```

I found that after removing # symbol, the subject field populated well, but the # is required. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely has to do with that **#** character not being URL encoded.

Try mailto:firstname.lastname@gmail.com?subject=thread%23:1234123123123

And take a look at http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php when you have a chance.